# Scala http operations

Tags: http, scala

How do I perform the following in Scala?

- HTTP Get
- HTTP Get With custom headers
- HTTP Post

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try out [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/). A little difficult to grasp at first, but after a while I've started to like it. It works on top of HttpClient.

```
import dispatch.Http
import Http._
// Get
Http(url("http://youruri.com/yo") >>> System.out)
// Get with header
Http(url("http://youruri.com/yo") <:< Map("Accept" -> "application/json") >>> System.out)
// Post
Http(url("http://youruri.com/yo") << yourPostData >|)
```

Comment: The only problem with Dispatch is that you can hardly find a method with a meaningful name. Operator methods are everywhere. Your code may easily look like a Morse code.

Comment: I've got a project on github (https://github.com/thoraage/coffee-trader) where I tried the borders of what I could do with Dispatch and the RestHelpers of Lift. It provides some examples; which are otherwise impossible to search for on google (since it looks like morse code).

Comment: emoticons! someone will get really confused.

Comment: If you struggle with the operators, you might want to take a look at the overview page here: http://www.flotsam.nl/dispatch-periodic-table.html

Comment: OMG, this API brings out the worst in scala. An Api that is useless unless you have a cheatsheet in front of you all the time.

Answer (score 18):

You can simply use java.net.URL to send HTTP GET and HTTP POST requests. 
You can also set HTTP request headers on the HttpURLConnection like this:

```
val con = url.openConnection.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
con.setRequestProperty("Header", "Value")
```

I have written myself a utility class which does exactly this. You can see it here:

https://github.com/gruenewa/gruenewa-misc/blob/master/gruenewa-wsclient/src/main/scala/gruenewa/wsclient/Service.scala

Comment: https://github.com/gruenewa/gruenewa-wsclient/blob/master/src/main/scala/gruenewa/wsclient/Service.scala just returns 404

Comment: I fixed the link. Thank you, James.

Answer (score 11):

this is my own implementation of a simple Http client including cookies management. Maybe it will be useful for you. But I'm not sure if header modification is directly possible (it may require your own implementation of URLConnection).

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter
import java.net.{URLConnection, URL}

class Http(userAgent: String,
           encoding: String,
           HttpRequestTimeout: Int = 15000) {

  import collection.JavaConversions._
  import Implicits.wrapInputStream
  import java.net.URLEncoder.encode

  var cookies = Map[String, String]()

  private def loadCookies(conn: URLConnection) {
    for ((name, value) <- cookies) conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", name + "=" + value)
  }

  private def saveCookies(conn: URLConnection) {
    conn.getHeaderFields.lift("Set-Cookie") match {
      case Some(cList) => cList foreach { c =>
        val (name,value) = c span { _ != '=' }
        cookies += name -> (value drop 1)
      }
      case None =>
    }
  }

  private def encodePostData(data: Map[String, String]) =
    (for ((name, value) <- data) yield encode(name, encoding) + "=" + encode(value, encoding)).mkString("&")

  def Get(url: String) = {
    val u = new URL(url)
    val conn = u.openConnection()
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent)
    conn.setConnectTimeout(HttpRequestTimeout)

    loadCookies(conn)

    conn.connect

    saveCookies(conn)

    conn.getInputStream.mkString
  }

  def Post(url: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
    val u = new URL(url)
    val conn = u.openConnection

    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent)
    conn.setConnectTimeout(HttpRequestTimeout)

    loadCookies(conn)

    conn.setDoOutput(true)
    conn.connect

   val wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream())
    wr.write(encodePostData(data))
    wr.flush
    wr.close


    saveCookies(conn)

    conn.getInputStream.mkString
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your loadCookies implementation works for multiple cookies, here is my suggestion: conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies.map{case (name, value) => name + "=" + value}.mkString("; "))

Comment: From whence cometh `Implicits.WrapInputStream`  i can not find that even by googling.

Comment: Anyways the same can be accomplished with `@inline def readStream(is: InputStream) = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).mkString` -except not implicits.

Answer (score 8):

While I appreciate the Dispatch library for all it's worth, the syntax still confuses me a bit.

Someone directed me to [scalaj-http the other day](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) which seems a little easier

Answer (score 4):

Regarding simply GETting data from URL. If you don't want to use external sources, then:

```
  val in = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://some.your.url/params?start&here", 
                                   "utf-8")
  for (line <- in.getLines)
    println(line)
```

For all other stuff, you can choose any method you like from answers above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Antonin Brettsnajdr's answer, a simply version of uploading a file using POST

```
val conn = new URL("http://myserver.appspot.com/upload").openConnection()
conn.setDoOutput(true)
conn.connect
val input = new FileInputStream(file)
val buffer = new Array[Byte](2 * 1024 * 1024)
Stream.continually(input.read(buffer)).takeWhile(_ != 1).foreach(conn.getOutputStream.write(_))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [spray-client](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-client/).  The documentation is lacking (it took me some digging to find out [how to make GET requests with query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463387/scala-url-with-query-string-parser-and-builder-dsl)) but it's a great option if you are already using spray.  We're using it at [AI2](http://allenai.org/) over [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) because the operators are less symbolic and we're already using spray/actors.

```
import spray.client.pipelining._

val url = "http://youruri.com/yo"
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = addHeader("X-My-Special-Header", "fancy-value") ~ sendReceive

// Get with header
pipeline(Get(url)) map (_.entity.asString) onSuccess { case msg => println(msg) }

// Get with header and parameters
pipeline(Get(Uri(url) withParams ("param" -> paramValue)) map (_.entity.asString) onSuccess { case msg => println(msg) }

// Post with header
pipeline(Post(url, yourPostData)) map (_.entity.asString) onSuccess { case msg => println(msg) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used Dispatch, Spray Client and the Play WS Client Library...None of them were simply to use or configure. So I created a simpler HTTP Client library which lets you perform all the classic HTTP requests in simple one-liners.

See an example:

```
import cirrus.clients.BasicHTTP.GET

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object MinimalExample extends App {

  val html = Await.result(Cirrus(GET("https://www.google.co.uk")), 3 seconds)

  println(html)
}
```

... produces ...

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-GB">...</html>
```

The library is called Cirrus and is available via Maven Central

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.godis" % "cirrus_2.11" % "1.4.1"
```

The documentation is available on GitHub

```
https://github.com/Godis/Cirrus
```