# Scala http library for google app engine : scalaj-http vs dispatch vs?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, scala

From the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564074/scala-http-operations), There are two external libraries to use for http operation. It seems that dispatch has more visibility while scalaj-http is easy to use as stated there. Thus, I am more inclined toward scalaj-http. I want to use the http library in google app engine, where there are restraints. For standard Java, there is a work around for it from [here](http://esxx.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html). I would like to get advice on what would be the best approach to use Scala in Google app engine(this is not for Lift framework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally am very happy with Dispatch. There are several [executors](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Choose+an+Executor.html), including one for App Engine, `dispatch-gae`.