# Scala - URL with Query String Parser and Builder DSL

Tags: parsing, scala, url, query-string, dsl

In Scala how do I build up a URL with query string parameters programmatically?

Also how can I parse a `String` containing a URL with query string parameters into a structure that allows me to edit the query string parameters programmatically?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following library can help you parse and build URLs with query string parameters (Disclaimer: This is my own library): https://github.com/lemonlabsuk/scala-uri

It provides a DSL for building URLs with query strings:

```
val uri = "http://example.com" ? ("one" -> 1) & ("two" -> 2)
```

You can parse a uri and get the parameters into a `Map[String,List[String]]` like so:

```
val uri = parseUri("http://example.com?one=1&two=2").query.params
```

Answer (score 15):

Spray has a very [efficient URI parser](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/Uri.scala). Usage is like so:

```
import spray.http.Uri
val uri = Uri("http://example.com/test?param=param")
```

You can set the query params like so:

```
uri withQuery ("param2" -> "2", "param3" -> 3")
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this outside of spray? Looking at the source seems like it's pretty coupled into other parts of spray.

Comment: You will only need the [`spray-http`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-http/) module which is pretty small. It only contains the model for HTTP requests and responses. It doesn't contain any server or client code.

Comment: @theon how do we use this Spray Routing? Here is my code

    val request: HttpRequest = Get(api)
    val pipeline: Future[SendReceive] = {
      for {
        Http.HostConnectorInfo(connector, _) <- IO(Http) ? Http.HostConnectorSetup(AppnexusSegmentService.AppnexusBaseUrl)
      } yield sendReceive(connector)
    }

    Await.result(pipeline.flatMap { client => client.apply(request)}, 15.seconds)

Comment: spray-http depends on Akka :-( ... Pulling this sort of dependency just for the sake of parsing a URI looks like overengineering.

Comment: Good point @RichardGomes. I was surprised considering `spray-http` is only meant to be the model of HTTP data structures. Why does it [need Akka](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-http)?

Comment: Since it is depended scope, you might be able omit it and have the Uri parsing code might still work. Still odd though.

Answer (score 4):

Theon's library looks pretty nice.  But if you just want a quickie encode method, I have this one.  It deals with optional parameters, and also will recognize JsValues from [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) and compact print them before encoding.  (Those happen to be the two things I have to worry about, but you could easily extend the match block for other cases you want to give special handling to)

```
import java.net.URLEncoder
def buildEncodedQueryString(params: Map[String, Any]): String = {
  val encoded = for {
    (name, value) <- params if value != None
    encodedValue = value match {
      case Some(x:JsValue) => URLEncoder.encode(x.compactPrint, "UTF8")
      case x:JsValue       => URLEncoder.encode(x.compactPrint, "UTF8")
      case Some(x)         => URLEncoder.encode(x.toString, "UTF8")
      case x               => URLEncoder.encode(x.toString, "UTF8")
    }
  } yield name + "=" + encodedValue

  encoded.mkString("?", "&", "")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**sttp** provides a great URI interpolator for this.

See here the [Documentation](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/model/uri.html#uri-interpolator)

Here its example:

```
import sttp.client._
import sttp.model._

val user = "Mary Smith"
val filter = "programming languages"

val endpoint: Uri = uri"http://example.com/$user/skills?filter=$filter"

assert(endpoint.toString ==
  "http://example.com/Mary%20Smith/skills?filter=programming+languages")
```

As you can see it automatically encodes the needed parts.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch hasn't been mentioned yet.

https://dispatchhttp.org/Defining+requests.html

```
val myRequest = host("somehost.com") / "some" / "path" <<? Map("id" -> "12345")
```

Comment: Hi @Ashalynd! The URL seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

also useful: https://github.com/mobiworx/urlifier

```
val url = (http || "some-domain".de) ? german & version(1) & foobar
url.toString
```

Answer (score 0):

Try KFoundation's URL class. It is both a builder and a parser.

E.g.

```
val url1 = URL("http://exampel.net/path")
val url2 = url1/"subpath"        // -> http://exampel.net/path/subpath
val url3 = url2?("key"->"value") // -> http://exampel.net/path/subpath?key=value
```

API Doc: https://mscp.co/resouces/apidoc/kfoundation/scala/0.3/net/kfoundation/scala/io/URL.html
Dependency: https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.kfoundation/kfoundation-scala_2.13/0.3.1/jar