# Scala get content from REST API with header

Tags: scala, rest, http-headers

How do I get content from a REST API using Scala and passing a header?

There is a similar question to this on StackOverflow, but it is quite old, and the answers refer to libraries that have been discontinued.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564074/scala-http-operations) is the old question.

Comment: Gigahorse works well http://eed3si9n.com/gigahorse/request.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of options, to name a few:

- https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp
- https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/index.html
- https://github.com/dispatch/reboot (this is the first answer in the old question)

What to use is dependent on your use case and also preferred style.